# Android XML assign name and ID to Views

Tags: android, xml

I have an xml view containing elements like below. Is it possible to assign a name or class field to the Spinner view like it HTML objects?

```
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Profession: "
                android:id="@+id/labelProfession"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinnerProfession"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

The reason is i need to make a post request to the server by creating a hash map of string names and values.

I can obtain the Spinner values using the forloop below but cannot get the label for use in posting, Unless i create a list with the corresponding textViews but  that would defeat the purpose of using a forloop.

```
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    data.put(ResponseDTO.TAG_ID, String.valueOf(mProfile.getmId()));
    data.put(ResponseDTO.TAG_PASSWORD, sharedPref.getString(ResponseDTO.TAG_PASSWORD,""));

    for (int i=0; i<mSpinnerList.size(); i++) {
         data.put(<<ValueOfCorrespondingTextView>>,mSpinnerList.get(i).getselection())
    }
```

Ideally the spinner View would have a name property with the value profession. Like the text in the above TextView

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Can you please give an example by showing what the user will see on the screen and describe what actions the user can take and what the results are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two solutions:

1. Create a parallel list of `TextView`s just like you create your list of `Spinner`s.
2. Create a custom view which includes both the `TextView` and corresponding `Spinner`. Now create a single list of these custom views.

Comment: I had went with the parallel List. It seems to be the easiest option
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `android:id="@+id/<insert_ID_here>"` tag in xml to give the Spinners each a unique ID that you can then reference in code, like so:

```
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerProfession"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

Then in code:

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an OnItemSelectedListener so you get the Adapter position instead of manually using the text of the spinner as per the documentation:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener     {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
    }
}
```